# using a men's mikvah twice if tamei or just once?

Tags: halacha, number, mikvah-ritual-bath

If someone is tamei, does that person have to use the mikvah twice or once is enough? If you have to use it twice how is this done?

Comment: Why do you suspect one must use it twice?

Comment: What do you mean by twice exactly? The existing answer assumes you mean dunking twice, but then you ask "how is this done", so maybe you mean something else?

Comment: The second time is to get rid of the Tamei water on your body. This is only necessary if there aren't 40 Saah in the Mikva. (_Purim Torah_)

Comment: By twice i mean to dry yourself and then to go back in. In the beis hamikdah the Kohanim would go 5 times

Comment: @DovidBenizri Do you have a source for that? I suspect you made it up or are confusing it with something else.

Comment: I know, it is in one of the maamarim of the Admor Shelita the Lubavitcher Rebbe

Comment: @DovidBenizri No Admor of Lubavitch is currently alive, so there can be no such thing as a maamar of his. Hence my suspicion that you are incorrect is confirmed.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why do you keep on contradicting me? It was said in one of his maamarim when he was in a guf gashmiyus. It is almost as if you hate me chasve shalom. Have ahavas yisroel

Comment: @DovidBenizri I'm contradicting you because you are saying falsehoods. That has nothing to do with hate.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly**, the Rambam in [הלכות מקוות פרק א](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a801.htm) says:

> והטובל פעמיים במקוה, הרי זה מגונה.

"Somebody who immerses twice is reprehensible." So it's clear that you never have to immerse more than once.

**Secondly**, there's no obligation for men who are tamei to go to a Mikvah nowadays.

As a result, your question "*does that person have to use the mikvah twice or once is enough*" is based on a false premise.

The correct answer is: If someone is tamei he doesn't have to go to the Mikvah at all.

Comment: But they would have to use the Mikva once _if they wanted to remove that impurity_. I think that is clearly what the OP meant to say.

Comment: @DoubleAA - True. And I answered that in the fist part.