# Restrictions/rules of men submerging in a Mikvah (according to Halacha)

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath

My family has had many beautiful experiences bathing in Mikve in Israel. We are wondering of there are restrictions in the number of times one can submerge in the Mikvah. There are 2 questions, but my feeling is that they are simple enough to ask in one post.  Please answer according to the rules of Jewish Law (Halacha) not Kabbalistic perspective.

1. Are there a certain number of "dunks" under the water that one should do that is most auspicious? Or is one time sufficient?
2. Can it be done many times during the day? (for example morning, midday and evening)

Are there any restrictions on the number of times one can dunk during a bath...? Or bathe in a Mikvah in a day?

Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 4):

According to halacha, the *tumot* (states of spiritual impurity) that are removed by a *mikvah* (e.g. *nidda*, *keri*), are removed with only one complete submersion. Anything beyond that is at best a custom, either related to mysticism, or as a precaution in case the prior immersions were invalid.

Comment: Good. Thank you. I'm also interested in if there are any restrictions on how many times one can bath or dunk. I will edit my question.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44851/759

Comment: Extra dunks in a warmed Mikva on Shabbat are probably completely Asur.